# Batch file - Delete all files in subdirectories which do not contain text in filename

Tags: command-line, batch

I'm looking to create a batch file that will delete all files in all subdirectories which do not contain the word '**export**' in the file name. I do this currently in Windows by using the '**NOT *export**' search string but that also lists the folders and I only want to delete files.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In your command line

```bat
for /f "delims=" %i in ('2^>nul dir /a:a /b /s ^| findstr /vi export')do del /q /a "%~fi"
```

- In your batch file

```bat
@echo off 

cd /d "D:\Full\Path\To\Your\Folder" 

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('2^>nul dir /a:a /b /s ^| findstr /vi export')do del /q /a "%%~fi"
```

---

An alternative to test the output and not perform any action, add an echo and see that it is operating as expected

```bat
:: In your command line 
...)do echo\del /q /a "%~fi"

:: In your batch file  
...)do echo\del /q /a "%%~fi"
```

---

**1.** List only files recursively: `dir /a:a /b /s`

**2.** Omit/filter files containing `export`: `| findstr /vi`

**3.** Operate it in `for /f` loop: `for /f "delims=" %i in ()do..`

**4.** Delete the files resulting from the loop: `del /q /a "%~fi"`

---

---

## Some further reading:

- **[`Dir /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html)**
- **[`For /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)**
- **[`For /F /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)**
- **[`Findstr /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)**
- **[Redirection: - `| >nul 2>nul 2>&1 <nul < > 2> 1>`](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)**
- **[An A-Z Index of Windows CMD commands on ss64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)**